# Example of a non compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Give an example of a noncompact metric space on which every real valued continuous function is uniformly continuous.

My attempt:
Consider $\mathbb Q$ with usual metric. As $\mathbb Q$ is not complete it is not compact. And the only continuous function from $\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb R$ are constant functions so they all are uniformly continuous. Is this correct?

Comment: From $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb Q$ there are only constant functions. *not* the other way round..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is not correct. Any continuous function on the real line restricted to $\mathbb Q$ is continuous.

Instead of this take $X=\mathbb N$ with the usual metric. Every function on this is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

In  general take every infinite set with the discrete metric.

Such set is not compact because in a discrete topological space,the compact sets are exactly the finite sets.

In a discrete topological space every continuous function is uniformly continuous.(I leave it to you as an easy exercise)